# How to show multiline text in a plotly icicle?

Tags: python, plotly, sunburst-diagram, icicles, icicle-diagram

I have a plotly icicle object named fig: `fig = px.icicle(df, names="people"...)`.

I want to show more text than just `df.people`. I tried the following:

`fig.update_traces(texttemplate=df.people + "\n" + "more text, but on a new line")`

But this does not produce a new line and instead prints a tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fig.update_traces(texttemplate='%{label}<br>%{customdata["more_text"]}')
fig.update_traces(customdata=df['more_text'])
```